# How to create new database when new client is created - Rails/postgresql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

My Requirement:
When admin create a client. I will save the client datas in Admin Database, 
Then a seperate database need to be created for client, with some static tables(customers, products, categories).

My question:
How to create the seperate database and how to do migration for that created database in Rails (Dynamically whenever admin create a client)

For Example:
If Admin create a ClientA, then clientA will be stored in Admin database, then fetch that name from that database,then  need to create a Database with name ClientA
if ClientB, then need to create a Database with name ClientB.

Comment: have you looked at  https://github.com/influitive/apartment  ?

Comment: Doon, Thanks for the update, I think this will help me a lot